# Ordinary Derivative of a Function of a Polynomial

Tags: calculus, derivatives, substitution, chain-rule

I want to find higher order derivatives of:
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{4}(x^2-1)^2+K; \quad\quad K=\text{constant} $$
However, I want to find the derivatives with respect to the variable $y$ where we are given the relationship that $x=2y-1$. My confusion is that following two approaches I am getting slightly different answers. Approach $1$ was to substitute from the start and then calculate the derivatives which gave (after expanding):
$$ f(2y-1) = 4y^4-8y^3+4y^2+K  $$
Differentiating and applying the chain rule to the RHS, gives:
$$ \frac{df}{dy}(2)=16y^3-24y^2+8y \implies \frac{df}{dy}=8y^3-12y^2+4y $$
My other approach was to calculate the derivatives with respect to $x$ and then use substitution afterwards:
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{4}x^4-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{4} +K $$
$$ \frac{df}{dx} = x^3-x $$
Using the chain rule, we have $\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{df}{dy}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$ . But this would imply:
$$ \frac{df}{dy} = 2\frac{df}{dx}=2(x^3-x)=2[(2y-1)^3-(2y-1)]=16y^3-24y^2+8y $$
I believe I should get the same thing with either approach but I can't tell why they disagree by a factor of $2$. For reference, what I'm actually interested in is the second and third derivatives of this function. Help would be much appreciated in resolving my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one is right. The factor of $2$ on  the left side in first approach is not there. When you view $f$ as   function of $y$ you get $4y^{4}-8y^{3}+4y^{2}+K$ and you just differentiate this w.r.t $y$. Chain rule is not involved here.

Comment: Appreciate your response. Why isn't the chain rule needed in the first one though? Because as the function is given it is: $f(2y-1)=4y^4-8y^3+4y^2+K$. Wouldn't that differ from whatever $f(y)$ is?

Comment: You are mixing derivatives on $y$ and derivatives on $2y-1$ (AKA $x$). Your third equation should read $\dfrac{df}{d(2y-1)}\cdot2$.

Comment: Oh so the $2$ I have from the chain rule would cancel with the $2$ in the denominator there? So basically, you can just ignore taking the chain rule because by design it will always cancel like that?

Comment: Further, if $\frac{df}{dy}=16y^3-24y^2+8y$ is correct, then I would just take the second derivative with respect to $y$ using the power rule to get $\frac{d^2f}{dy^2}=48y^2-48y+8$. And I would do the same to find higher and higher derivatives right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @joseph

Comment: thanks for the help!